# css style does not apply when press print button using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to print a table by pressing the print button using jquery but the styles applied to the table does not work.
here is my css

```
<style>
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
table td, table th{ border: 1px solid #73afb7; text-align:left;}    
</style>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#print').click(function(){   
       var divContents = $('#abc').html();
       var printWindow = window.open('', '', ',width=800');
       printWindow.document.write('<html>');
       printWindow.document.write('<body >');
       printWindow.document.write(divContents);
       printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
       printWindow.print();
       printWindow.close();
    });//end of print button click
});//end of ready function
```

html

```
<div id="abc">
   <table id="tbl">
    <tr>
       <th>S.No</th>
       <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>AYAZ</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

when press the print button the jquery prints the table contents without its borders

Comment: In your jQuery code you create a new window using `window.open` then new window is separate from the main window and won't share the CSS from it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a separate CSS with it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#print').click(function(){   
        var divContents = $('#abc').html();
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', ',width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html>');
        printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/print.css"/>');
        printWindow.document.write('<body >');
        printWindow.document.write(divContents);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    });//end of print button click
});//end of ready function
```

Your CSS have this:

```
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of print actually creates a new page. If u look at the link in that new page, you will see that its not the same as your website. So, even linking the css file like KunJ suggested wont work either.
I would suggest u take a look at: http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/jquery-print.html

Also take a look at "media types" in css.

The plugin can be fount at: http://plugins.jquery.com/PrintArea/

The print link/button:

```
<a href="#" rel="testprint" id="printa">Print</a>
```

rel="testprint" refers to the area u want to print

Jquery code:

```
$('#printa').click(function(e) {
    var container = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#' + container).printArea();
    return false;
});
```

as for css, you can include your css file with the media tag. Note that you will have to include it twice, or take use @media in your main css file.

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/style_1.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Remember to include some of the content of the linked page in your answer, just in case the link becomes unavailable.  That way your answer will still be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this between `<html>` and `<body>`:

```
printWindow.document.write('<html>');
printWindow.document.write('<head><style>');
printWindow.document.write('table {border-collapse:collapse;}');
printWindow.document.write('table td, table th{ border: 1px solid #73afb7; text-align:left;}');
printWindow.document.write('</style></head>');
printWindow.document.write('<body >');
```

Answer (score 0):

And why not:

```
<style>
@media print{
  table {border-collapse:collapse;}
  table td, table th{ border: 1px solid #73afb7; text-align:left;}
 }
</style>
```

Or

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css"/>
```

with external file

Answer (score 0):

Print CSS is a Cascading Style Sheet intended for print documents when users want to print the web page for reference

The media is now set to print and not screen:

```
  <!-- Include Print CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="URL to your print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Ref: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/